# 'dict' object has no attribute 'load'

Tags: python, json

I'm trying make script which open file, make some things in loop and then append returned value.

```
def test(key, site_key, url):
    while True:
        with open("tokens.json") as f:
            plik = json.load(f)
        if len(tasks_count) <= 10  or len(plik) == 0: 
            #do sth
```

And  I've got error 'dict' object has no attribute 'load' What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have probably something like `json = <some dict>` at some other place in your code.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille You are almost certainly correct. And this is the result of (1) people confusing the distinction between a `JSON` string and a Python object and (2) inadvertently redefining modules such as `json` because they reuse that name for variables because of (1).

Comment: Thank you, im dumb I've forgot about it